# Does the [immediate-reaction] tag describe something substantially different from the [reactions] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonymization

The [immediate-reaction](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immediate-reaction) tag currently has no tag info, but there are seven D&D 4e questions with the tag.

[reactions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reactions) is currently used on 92 questions, all but one of which are apparently for D&D 5e. ([The only other one is about *Mutants & Masterminds*.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99553/do-reactions-resolve-before-or-after-the-action-they-are-reacting-to) I recently found [another M&M question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139301/can-reaction-powers-by-default-be-disabled-as-a-free-action) it might apply to, which is what made me discover this issue.)

The tag info for the [reactions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reactions) tag says:

> For questions about reactions - an action taken by an entity in response to a trigger happening.

However, because [immediate-reaction](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immediate-reaction) has no tag info, I can't tell whether it falls under the same category as the [reactions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reactions) tag.

**Do these two tags describe essentially the same type of thing? If so, should they be synonymized?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are not the same thing and should not be synonymised.

[reaction](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reaction) is an action economy element of D&D 5e beside your action, move, and minor action. You spend it to do something.

[immediate-reaction](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immediate-reaction) and [immediate-interrupt](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immediate-interrupt) are timings on when a power occurs. They are not an action economy element and do not interact with D&D 4e's standard action, move action, and minor action.

I have added tag wikis to these two D&D 4e tags.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for asking about it.